# Using Scala kernel with Spark

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a problem with accessing data from S3 from Spark.
I have `spylon-kernel`installed for `JupyterHub` (which is Scala kernel with Spark framework integrtation). It uses `pyspark`. 
Unfortunately the newest pyspark still uses `hadoop-2.7.3` libraries. When I'm trying to access S3 bucket in Frankfurt region I get following Java exception:

> "*com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400,
>   AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: xxxxxxxxxx, AWS Error Code:
>   null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request*"

From my research it looks like it's `hadoop 2.7.3` problem. With newer versions `(3.1.1)` it works well locally but `pyspark` uses those `hadoop 2.7.3` jars and looks like it can't be changed. Can I do something about it? Maybe there is some way to tell `pyspark` to use `hadoop 3.1.1` jars? Or maybe there is other Scala kernel with Spark for `Jupyterhub` which uses `spark-shell` instead of `pyspark`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally fixed it... I will post an answer, maybe it will be useful for someone.

```
pip install toree

jupyter toree install --spark_home /path/to/your/spark/ --interpreters=Scala
```

This one works! :)